# WebApp down after adding master and vacuum in uwsgi ini file

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am having a super weird problem. Let me try to explain.
Our WebApp is running with `uwsgi`. 

**uwsgi ini file:**

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 4
threads = 2
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter=true
listen = 1000
harakiri = 300
harakiri-verbose = true
max-requests = 5000
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
plugins = python
home = /srv/www/python_env
chdir = /srv/www/app
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=appsphere.settings
module = appsphere.wsgi:application
socket = :8088
stats = :7088
logto2 = /var/log/uwsgi/access.log
buffer-size = 65535
post-buffering = 16384
```

Nginx is using upstream to proxy to port 8088 of the local machine.

```
upstream srdjangow {
    server 127.0.0.1:8088 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
}
```

Everything was running.

then I added two more options in my uwsgi ini file **master** and **vacuum** making it like this;

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 4
threads = 2
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter=true
listen = 1000
harakiri = 300
harakiri-verbose = true
max-requests = 5000
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
plugins = python
home = /srv/www/python_env
chdir = /srv/www/app
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=appsphere.settings
module = appsphere.wsgi:application
socket = :8088
stats = :7088
logto2 = /var/log/uwsgi/access.log
buffer-size = 65535
post-buffering = 16384
master = true
vacuum = true
```

I restarted everything and now nothing works.
Not even after removing all the changes that I did. 
All I get is this in error.log of nginx.

```
2016/04/07 15:46:28 [error] 1067#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
```

What sins have I committed ?